# Переход между Activity. Xamarin Android

Tags: android, c#, xamarin

Есть 2 Активити. На каждой из них кнопка "перейти на 1/2 активити". Нужно чтобы происходил именно переход, а не создание нового окна. То-есть при первом нажатии на "перейти на 2" вторая активити должна создаться, а при последующих нажатиях происходит именно переход (Активити не закрываются, а в паузе). У меня же получается, что создается куча куча окон. Нужно какое-то отслеживание состояния активити...и вместо StartActivity что-то другое.

Answer (score 1):

1. Как вариант использовать фрагменты, а не Активити.
2. Поиграться с атрибутом активити launchMode. Описание тут https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Answer (score 0):

[image]
В книге разработка Android приложений такое описание решения проблемы.
Для предотвращения создания новой Activity используют флаг. ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity));
intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ReorderToFront;
StartActivity(intent);
```

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст ответа можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста ответа.

Comment: Спасибо конечно, может кому-то это все-таки будет полезно. Я же сменил направление разработки)